# OpenGL, Android and Galaxy S3

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I'm using a `GLSurfaceView` to display the camera image on my Galaxy Note 3. With a fragment shader I'm rendering the camera image with different effects. This works fine on Galaxy S4 and Note 3 but makes trouble on Galaxy S3.

I get the following error message:

```
03-13 13:16:30.971 E/OpenGLTools( 9275): Could not compile shader 35632:
03-13 13:16:30.971 E/OpenGLTools( 9275): 0:117: S0001: Type mismatch in arithmetic operation between 'vec3' and 'vec4'
```

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main() {
    vec3 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord).rgb;

    float gray = dot(color, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
    color = vec3(gray);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

And here is the vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uTexMatrix;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
    vTextureCoord = (uTexMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;

}
```

Could someone explain me how to solve this error?
I think the problem occurs when I try to set the `gl_FragColor`, but I thought this is always a `vec4`?

Comment: it is always a vec4. the snipped looks fine to me. can you post the rest of the shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem with the following code:

```
void main() {
    vec3 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord).rgb;

    float gray = dot(color, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
    color = vec3(gray);

    gl_FragColor.rgb = color;
}
```

Comment: Did Sergey's version work? It's a little odd not to write to all of `gl_FragColor`.

Comment: Sergey's code didn't work because the gl_FragColor is only vec3 on a Galaxy S3.
As I understood that code, the fourth float in gl_FragColor is the alpha channel. My input is a 2DTexture of a camera, so the alpha channel is always 1.0

Comment: That's very strange: `gl_FragColor` is *always* a vec4. If the destination buffer has no alpha channel, the alpha component might still be used for blending (or otherwise ignored).

Answer (score 1):

This is more portable between different mobile GLSL implementations:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
    float gray = dot( color, vec4(0.299, 0.587, 0.114, 0.0) );
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gray, gray, gray, 1.0);
}
```

In general, try to omit implicit casts from your code.

Comment: I was going to suggest something like this, even though I can't see any error in the original code. You seem to have slipped in an extraneous 0.0 into the vec3 constant.

Comment: But what is the difference to my code? And why is my code working on my Note 3 but not on an S3?

Comment: @chris6523: You have different typecasts in your code.

Comment: Those devices use gpus from different vendors (ARM mali vs Qualcomm Adreno). GLSL compilers are implemented independently by each vendor, and unfortunately contain (different) bugs. I have had to rearrange perfectly conforming code (sometimes trivially) to work around them. I would be very interested to know if Sergey's suggestion fixes your problem.

Comment: Could you clarify "crashes"? Does the shader compile?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to really "test" it on a Galaxy S3. I have developed an Android application and implemented ACRA. After changing those lines to the my "new" code, I didn't receive any new errors.